# Obtain the number of rows before a value, based on condition

Tags: r

My first `data.frame` is structured as follows:

```
structure(list(Trial = c("Left - 180 degrees", "Left - 300 degrees", 
"Left - 60 degrees", "Right - 180 degrees", "Right - 300 degrees", 
"Right - 60 degrees", "Left - 180 degrees", "Left - 300 degrees", 
"Left - 60 degrees", "Right - 180 degrees", "Right - 300 degrees", 
"Right - 60 degrees"), Region = c("Hamstring", "Hamstring", 
"Hamstring", "Hamstring", "Hamstring", "Hamstring", "Quad", "Quad", 
"Quad", "Quad", "Quad", "Quad"), PeakPower = c(118, 90, 
156, 105, 90, 140, 146, 111, 247, 186, 
133, 270)), .Names = c("Trial", "Region", "PeakPower"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I wish to locate each `PeakPower` value, according to `Trial` and `Region` in another data frame below, called `RawData`. I also wish to calculate the time (each row = 1 second) taken to reach `PeakPower`. This is simply the number of rows between 0 and each `PeakPower` value. For example:

```
PeakPower <- c(0,0,0,0,3,5,8,19,20,0,0,0,0,0,60,65,88,90,94,99,100,105,107,118,114,100)
Trial <- c("Left - 180 degrees")
Region <- c("Hamstring")
RawData <- data.frame(cbind(PeakPower, Trial, Region))
```

The time to reach `PeakPower` for the Left - 180 degrees trial and hamstring region would be 10 rows or 10 seconds.

How do I complete this in R?

Thank you.

Comment: @HubertL going into Excel and calling it out manually! I would like to know how to do this in R to automate and speed up the process.

Comment: In your second dataset, Region is "Left - 180 degrees" while in te first one it is "Hamstring"... Could you please try to clarify what you have and what you want?

Comment: @HubertL edited. Apologies - thanks for the pick up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With package `dplyr`:

```
data_frame(PeakPower, Trial, Region) %>% 
  group_by(Trial,Region) %>% 
  mutate(Max=which.max(PeakPower)) %>% 
  filter(row_number()<=Max) %>%
  arrange(desc(row_number()))%>%
  mutate(Min=which.min(PeakPower)) %>% 
  filter(row_number()<Min) %>%
  summarise(PeakPower=max(PeakPower), Time=n()) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 1 × 4
               Trial    Region PeakPower  Time
               <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <int>
1 Left - 180 degrees Hamstring       118    10
```